# Proving that $f$ is constant without Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if $f$ is an entire function, and there is a nonempty disk
such that $f$ does not attain any values in the disk, then $f$ is constant.

I have seen several proofs of this with Liouville's theorem, but is it provable without Liouville's theorem?

Comment: I seriously doubt that.

Comment: You would want to prove Picard's Little Theorem without Liouville's Theorem. Not sure if that would be good pedagogy though.

Comment: I haven't worked through the details, but you should be able to use this to prove Liouville's theorem. Given $f$ which is entire and bounded, compose with a mobius transformation to get $Mf$ entire and omitting a disk. Then using this, $Mf$ is constant, thus so is $f$. With this in mind, any proof of this theorem has to basically prove Liouville's theorem along the way.

Comment: HallaSurvivor is correct; this result is equivalent to Liouville's theorem. The point is that you can move the disk to infinity with a Mobius transformation.